# wp nav menu without label

Tags: php, menus, html

I have a menu on wordpress using this

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order','menu_class' => 'navlink', 'container' => false, 'theme_location' => 'header-menu') ); ?>
```

the output is like this

```
<div class="navlink">
<ul>
<li class="page_item page-item-2 current_page_item active"><a href="http://michaelpon.tk/about/">About</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-6"><a href="http://michaelpon.tk/skills/">Skills</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-4"><a href="http://michaelpon.tk/project/">Project</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-8"><a href="http://michaelpon.tk/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

now i want is to display my menu without the labels about, skills... is it possible? i tried using the menu and display it via widgets but the menu won't allow me to add pages without any labels. it automatically removes the page from the menu.
like this.

```
<li class="page_item page-item-2 current_page_item active"><a href="http://michaelpon.tk/about/"></a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-6"><a href="http://michaelpon.tk/skills/"></a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-4"><a href="http://michaelpon.tk/project/"></a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-8"><a href="http://michaelpon.tk/contact/"></a></li>
```

Is their any possible way other than using static html? I'm using foundationpress as my theme.
I will display the label of my menu using pseudo element

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/phxzka6u/**)

Comment: Do you mean without anchor text? I think you shouldn't do that; anchor text is very important. A better solution, from my point of view, would be make it invisible for normal users and visible only for screen readers with CSS.

Comment: edited the question...